# Unable to load a listener zkspring-webflow.jar

Tags: tomcat, zk

I am using tomcat 7.0.76.0 and zk framework 8.0.2.2.

I have all my zk lib files in tomcat lib folder.
When I start tomcat, I see the following errors in the log:

```
SEVERE: Unable to load a listener, [null:jar:file:/usr/share/java/tomcat/zkspring-webflow.jar!/metainfo/zk/config.xml:22:12]
Dec 28 14:18:56 gtswtappdev1 server[22917]: org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: jar:file:/usr/...ar!/metainfo/zk/config.xml:22:12: Unable to load org.zkoss.spring.init.WebflowWebAppInit
Dec 28 14:18:56 gtswtappdev1 server[22917]: at org.zkoss.zk.ui.sys.ConfigParser.parseClass(ConfigParser.java:929)
Dec 28 14:18:56 gtswtappdev1 server[22917]: at org.zkoss.zk.ui.sys.ConfigParser.parseListener(ConfigParser.java:287)
Dec 28 14:18:56 gtswtappdev1 server[22917]: at org.zkoss.zk.ui.sys.ConfigParser.parseListeners(ConfigParser.java:281)
Dec 28 14:18:56 gtswtappdev1 server[22917]: at org.zkoss.zk.ui.sys.ConfigParser.parseConfigXml(ConfigParser.java:219)
Dec 28 14:18:56 gtswtappdev1 server[22917]: at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.WebManager.<init>(WebManager.java:133)
Dec 28 14:18:56 gtswtappdev1 server[22917]: at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener23.contextInitialized(HttpSessio
```

After a bit of research, I found the exact problem in zk forum:
https://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZKSPRING-23

However, they have no solution to this issue.
Any recommendation on how I can remove those errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this path, `/usr/share/java/tomcat/, a shared library folder? ZK doesn't support to put jar in a shared library folder.
Could you package  zkspring-webflow jar into your application WAR?